# Java on Mac: Cannot read resources in executable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

This code works fine when I run it from Eclipse, but not from an executable jar:

```
String str = "";
ImageIcon icon = null;
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/splash.jpg");
if (is != null) {
    icon= new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(is));  
} else {
    str = "stream is null";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str,"A title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,icon);
```

The dialog is displayed but no stream is returned from getResourceAsStream, irrespective of how I write the path. Inspection of the jar shows that splash.jpg is located in the images-folder, as it should be. The jar is created using Eclipse's export of "Runnable jar" with "Package required libraries into JAR" selected.

I know this question has been asked before, and I have read many (most?) of the answers and tried many different alternative solutions. But nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated. (I'm using java 8 and Eclipse Mars on OSX Maverick.)

EDIT: Sorry for not listing the alternatives I have tried. It's just that I haven't kept notes and I cannot remember all. As far as path goes I have tried all combinations of "/" and "images" (and "resources"). I have also tried getting a URL via getResource(), both from class and class loader. No matter what I do I get null (no exception thrown in example above).

Here's what the structure looks like in Eclipse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIiEi.png

And here's what it looks like in the jar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAnmr.png

Comment: Please share the things you've tried, we can't help if all we have to go on is "I've tried a bunch of things".

Comment: Perhaps show us a screen shot of the portion of the jar that contains the images?  Saying "irrespective of how I write the path" is not helpful -- you need to tell us what you've tried.  Does it just return null or give an error message?

Comment: You need to put that images file right next to your .java files.

Comment: @BitNinja I tried that (images folder and main folder both under src in eclipse). Didn't work.

Comment: @palun And then also remove the first `/` in your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshots, the file is named "splash.JPG", and you're asking for "splash.jpg", which is a difference in case. The Mac filesystem is case-insensitive. The JAR entry reading code may not be. Try changing your string in the `getResource` call to have the same case as the file name or vice versa.

Comment: I changed the filename and now it works fine. Thanks! (Seems I cannot vote as I am too new to the forum (?).)